# How does the expression '^$' in SED is arrived?

Tags: regex, sed

I know that `$` means the last character, and the `^` means the first character.
I have seen the example in SED to delete all the blank lines using this macro.

`sed '/^$/d' <file_name>` to delete all the blank lines. I was trying to understand this expression `^$`, how some one has arrived to this expression? Does it mean that delete all the lines whose first and last characters are same? What is meant by that combination `^$`?

Comment: if $ is the last line. Then, why this is used to append in the suders file. sed -i '/ADMINS/s/$/, joshis1/' /etc/sudoers. It is like append ,joshis1 at the pattern matched at the line ADMINS. Note append is done through the $ symbol. Also, ADMINS line is not the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is actually for regular expression on not specific for 'sed'.
The sed utility is using regular expressions for stream/line editor.

The ^ (circumflex or caret) means look only at the beginning of the target string.
The $ (dollar) means look only at the end of the target string.
So, /^$/ means a line with nothing in between the beginning and the end of the line.

Answer (score 7):

`^` is not a first character, it is "before first character". `$` is not the last character as well, it is "end of line". `^$` means there's nothing in between those two so it's just a blank line.

Comment: if $ is the last line. Then, why this is used to append in the suders file. sed -i '/ADMINS/s/$/, joshis1/' /etc/sudoers. It is like append ,joshis1 at the pattern matched at the line ADMINS. Note append is done through the $ symbol. Also, ADMINS line is not the last line.

Comment: `$` means different things depending on whether it is line number or in regexp. In regexp it means "End of line". As a line number it means "last line". Your command `sed -i '/ADMINS/s/$/, joshis1/' /etc/sudoers` finds a line that contains `ADMINS` pattern and replaces "nothing in the end" with `, joshis1`, which is thus appending `, joshis1` to the end of that line.